How to check for invalid messages in Netty Server decoder?
I am implementing Netty server for some proprietary TCP protocol. Each message in this protocol is in ASCII and has the following structure:

4 bytes of fixed header (string AABB)
4 bytes message length
x bytes message body, based on length

For example 55AA000512345 is valid message that the server can receive and it has a body 12345.
I have implemented this decoder based on the standard LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder and it works fine:
public class CustomLengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder extends LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder {

    public CustomLengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(int maxFrameLength, int lengthFieldOffset, int lengthFieldLength) {
        super(maxFrameLength, lengthFieldOffset, lengthFieldLength);
    }

    @Override
    protected long getUnadjustedFrameLength(ByteBuf buf, int offset, int length, ByteOrder order) {
        try {
            return Long.parseLong(buf.toString(offset, length, CharsetUtil.US_ASCII));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            throw new DecoderException(nfe);
        }
    }
}

new CustomLengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(9999, 4, 4);

The problem is that this decoder does not validate the fixed header, so for example when I receive a message XXXX0008AAAA, I would like to evaluate this as an invalid message, ignore it, and wait for the proper message starting with the prefix AABB. I am not sure how to implement this properly. Should I make a second decoder or inherit some functionality from LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder?
Here is a working example for my current implementation.
